# How to deterministically handle situation in NodeJS where asynchronous functions use up memory faster than garbage collection reclaims it?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, non-deterministic

I've run into a problem where I'm running out of memory because garbage collection doesn't free up resources efficiently enough to prevent many asynchronous functions from using it all up.

I am not keeping references to any objects made during the asynch functions so they should all be able to be collected once they go out of scope.

I'm recursing asynchronously through a directory tree making a plain text file to accompany every HTML file using cheerio.

I realize I can but some kind of delay or batching in to keep the script trying to convert huge numbers of files at once.

But how can I do so deterministically? Sometimes it works, sometimes I get an exception from cheerio but each time while working on a different file, which is why I think it's memory exhaustion and non deterministic.

I believe there's no way in JavaScript or NodeJS to exert control over garbage collection. What can be done?

My code:

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , path = require('path')
  , cheerio = require('cheerio')
  ;

var processFile = function(filePath) {
  var ext = path.extname(filePath)
    , res = false
    ;
  if (ext === '.html' || ext === '.htm') {
    res = true;

    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
      var $;

      try {
        $ = cheerio.load(data);

        $('script').remove();

        // HTML to text
        var pt = $('body').text().replace(/(\s|\r?\n)+/gm, function (ws) {
          return /\r?\n.*\r?\n/.test(ws) ? '\n\n' : ' ';
        }).trim();

        var txtFilePath = filePath.substr(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('.')) + '.txt';
        fs.writeFile(txtFilePath, pt, function(err) {
          console.log('wrote "' + txtFilePath + '"');
        });
      } catch (exy) {
        console.log('## BANG!', filePath);
        throw exy;
      }
    });
  }
  return res;
}

var walkP = function(dir, done) {
  fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    var pending = list.length;
    if (!pending) return done(null);
    list.forEach(function(file) {
      file = path.resolve(dir, file);
      fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
        if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
          walkP(file, function(err, res) {
            if (!--pending) done(null);
          });
        } else {
          processFile(file);
          if (!--pending) done(null);
        }
      });
    });
  });
};

walkP(process.cwd(), function(err, res) {
  console.log('Walked ' + res);
});
```

Comment: Driveby closevoter has nothing to say?

Comment: Nodejs is signle threaded, so for your case to take control over this kind of files management your could use node clusters or at least spawn child processes as needed.

Comment: @hippietrail What about `--expose-gc`?

Comment: @stdob--: I've read about that since I hit this problem but people always seem to mention it with a bunch of caveats. I'm not sure that it would make things deterministic even if it might make things work sometimes in some circumstances.

Comment: @hippietrail Maybe it seems to me, but the problem is  in the recursion: function "walkP" is the call self a lot of time and causes a stack overflow.

Comment: @stdob--: That could be. The exception I catch from cheerio, a mature module to my knowledge, does not specify either lack of memory or stack overflow. An internal object reference is `null` when an attempt is made to dereference it. I've made a version where the HTML to text part is done in a loop with `setTimeout(1)` and it works but I'm not certain I've made it deterministic or it's just a fluke that it now works on my particular setup.